# What is the subject of sentence with ください?

Tags: subsidiary-verbs, subjects, giving-and-receiving, deixis

For example, what is the subject of the following sentence?

> 八時に来るようにしてください。

The speaker or the opponent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope I've understood you correctly:

くださる means 'to give'.

> (You) give (me) the favour of making sure to come at 8 o'clock. = Please make sure to come at 8 o'clock

The person doing the giving (you) is the opponent which is the **subject** of くださる. The speaker (me) is the **indirect object**.